# file_get_contents returns the text in an html file

Tags: php

I am facing a problem with file_get_contents recently...
When I use it to fetch webpages from the web, it works fine, but when I use it to open a local page it outputs only the text in the page.
i.e. when I use it as

```
file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
```

and echo it I get the google page and its entire structure but when I use

```
file_get_contents("localfile.html");
```

and echo it it just outputs the text in the page without the tags.

Comment: Always look at the source code of the output, not the browser's rendering.

Comment: The source code will be perfect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because, HTML tags are parsed by the browser. Use [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) this way:

```
htmlentities(file_get_contents("localfile.html"));
```

But one thing, when you see the source of the file, it shows you what you need. Also, alternatively you can output this inside a `textarea`.

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlentities(file_get_contents("localfile.html")); ?></textarea>
```