# Reading PHP file with fread

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on cake php. 
I want to develop a generalized application in which i will give in folder names. 
Those folders will be basically the links of other application, also on cake php. 
Now the main objective is that my app will go inside the controllers' folder and first list out all the controllers, and then look inside that controller and read each inside function, and show them as separate functions. 
I used fread and file_get_content, 
but they are not reading properly even the string which is returned as file contents has some text missing from start. 
Adding to that i remove the starting php tags from controllers it reads whole file but the thing is in this way the controller wont work. 
anyone having solution of this please ?

Comment: Well lets see what it is you are trying so we can help you fix it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726205/file-get-contents-returns-the-text-in-an-html-file. U will have to use htmlentities if u want to show unparsed PHP

Comment: @DarkBee 
It worked :) 
lets proceed to working inside that file

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Folder` class from CakePHP core or even [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) to get a list with all of your controllers. Then instead read the content of your files you could use [`ReflectionClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to collect information about your classes. `ReflectionClass::getMethods()` can help you to build your methods list. You could also consider just the public methods if desired making use of `ReflectionMethod::isPublic()` method.

Depending on your implementation you'll have to load the controller classes